# i try to change magento luma colors

Tags: magento2

in `/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/ro_RO/css` .

I can see all the files but the document inside  no. so there is no way I can make changes.  What am I doing wrong ?

**magento 2- filezilla**

Answer (score 0):

you do not have to change your css in `pub/static` because this folder is only for generated files.

The files you are interested in, are in `vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma`. Change here your .less and recompile.

Less compilation is a somewhat complex topic, I suggest you take a look at the [devDocs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-preprocess.html), a quick way to see your changes is to remove the following folders:

```
/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/
/var/view_preprocessed/css
/var/view_preprocessed/html
/var/view_preprocessed/source
```

and run:

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: It is considered very bad practice to modify Magento's core files. Add your own theme that overrides the Luma theme for future compatibility.

Comment: I used it as an example. The same example used by the person who made the question. The topic is very entry level, I think is better to learn step by step.

Comment: [Magento docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-practice.html) show a perfect example on how to customise.